# Pandas merge statement not giving me the difference between dataframes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

can't seem to get this pandas merge working properly. I want to know the difference between df_file_dates_from_directory and df_file_dates_from_sql BEFORE merge which should be 20171211 - 20171218. Can some one point out what is wrong with my merge statement please? here are the print outs of the df's

```
df_file_dates_from_directory
0     20171211
1     20171212
2     20171213
3     20171214
4     20171215
5     20171218
6     20171219
7     20171220
8     20171221
9     20171222
10    20171226
11    20171227

df_file_dates_from_sql BEFORE merge
    File_date
0    20171219
1    20171220
2    20171221
3    20171222
4    20171226
5    20171227

      #new_df  = df_file_dates_from_sql.merge( df_file_dates_from_directory['File_date'].to_frame(), indicator=True, how='outer')
      new_df = pd.merge(df_file_dates_from_sql, df_file_dates_from_directory['File_date'], on='File_date', how='outer', suffixes=('_left', '_right' ) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [364]: (d1.to_frame(name='File_date')
             .merge(d2, how='outer', indicator=True)
             .query("_merge == 'left_only'")
             .drop('_merge',1))
Out[364]:
   File_date
0   20171211
1   20171212
2   20171213
3   20171214
4   20171215
5   20171218
```

Comment: No luck got AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_frame' using       new_df = (df_file_dates_from_sql.to_frame(name='File_date').merge(df_file_dates_from_directory['File_date'], how='outer', indicator=True).query("_merge == 'left_only'").drop('_merge',1)) where did I screw up please AND thanks so much

Comment: @sio2bagger, if `df_file_dates_from_directory` is a DataFrame (not a Series like in your question), then just remove `.to_frame(name='File_date')`. You might also need to specify "joining" column names: `left_on=...`, `right_on=...` ...

Comment: sorry I said they were both data frames in the question text, my fault I should have been more clear. also d1 is df_file_dates_from_sql and d2 is df_file_dates_from_directory['File_date']. Rght now I am getting TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable BUT you have given me more than enough to be going on with. thank you so much for laying the next clue in my pandas treasure hunt :-)

Comment: hey @MaxU  ALL done ! sorry I just saw how to do that. It's still blowing up but I am sure that your answer will guide me to the solution. Thanks again